# How to translate Umlauts and other International characters to US character set?

Tags: internationalization, international

Is there a "translation table" that shows how International characters map to the US character set.

For example, German umlauts can be translated like:

```
ä = ae  
ö = oe 
ü = ue
```

or French characters like:

```
è = e
é = e
```

etc ...

Comment: Do you actually need a table to *personally* look at? There are libraries that can just do it for you, for example. If that's an option, you should specify what programming language you're working in. (I don't have anything immediately at hand; I've just seen it while poking around in others' code.) You could probably dig something workable out of those libs, for that matter.

Comment: There are a *lot* of "international characters", and there isn't unanimity on how to transliterate them to the Latin alphabet. E.g. the Cyrillic letter Ц can be ts (as in Yeltsin), tz, cz, ... The Corpus of Contemporary American includes all three of `tzar`, `czar`, and `tsar`.